# regex not removing square brackets

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i am using the following regex `[^a-zA-Z\d!-]` pattern in c# to clean special characters from  filename so i can pull basic information from it and build initial class property values from it

how ever no matter what i seem to do it wont clean the square brackets from the string according to regex builder it should be matching the square brackets but is not removing them when i run the replace operation

any help as to why would be greatly appreciated and a fix would be nice too =)

the code im using in c# is as follows:

```
var removeSpecChar = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z\d!-]");               

msa = msa.Substring(0, msa.Length - 4);
removeSpecChar.Replace(msa, " ").Trim();
```

Comment: For what value of `msa` does the above code fail? Is the pattern exactly the same, or is this a part of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't try, but you really should escape the `-` in characher sets:

```
var removeSpecChar = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z\d!\-]");
```

Also note that `\d` is not equivalent to `0-9`, it matches any unicode digit (including arabic digits etc.). So you may want to change that if this isn't your intention.

Comment: No need to escape the dash at the end of the character class. This isn't the reason for his problem.

Comment: ok im simply a dumbass at 6am   i was running the regex but not assigning the result