# Replace square brackets in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace, escaping

There is a string which is innerHTML of an HTML page. In that, there are contents ...which I need to replace part by parts...I have replaced a few by the following formula.

```
string formatted = str.replace("*", "")
```

This will replace all * in that HTML page with blank. But I need to replace following contents to blank as well.

[Issue /]

[-Select- /]

[    ]

[Upload]

[Issue /]

So I used code as below:

```
str.replace("[Issue \/]", "")
str.replace("[-Select- \/]", "")
str.replace("[    ]", "")
str.replace("[Upload]", "")
str.replace("[Issue \/]", "")
```

But I couldn't see any replaces for the contents in the HTML content for the above string.

And there is an image button in the HTML. That image button also I need to replace.

The HTML code of the image button is below:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnAddHotel" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Style Library/images/icon-add.gif" OnClick="btnAddHotel_Click" OnClientClick="return HideAllTicketValidations();" />
```

How to replace all these strings?

Comment: I have no clue what you're actually trying to do. What are you trying to replace? What are some examples of the input string? What are the respective desired outputs? What does "not working" mean? And what does the random chunk of HTML have to do with anything?

Comment: See the posts 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811969/regular-expression-to-replace-square-brackets-with-angle-brackets and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840992/regex-not-removing-square-brackets

Comment: from your code, I can bet that `str.replace("*","")` _does not work_ as well.

Comment: god just tell me how to replace square brackets using this str.replace("[","") not working any other work around?

Comment: str.replace("[", "") works perfectly. Given a string like "something[else]" it will transform it into "somethingelse]", which is what it is supposed to do. The question is what do you want it to do? Please provide an example of your input string and what you would like to transform it to.

Comment: `-1` for soliciting an answer without any effort to clarify the question. Also I didn't get the last part with "html".

Answer (score 4):

str.Replace doesn't make the changes in place. Instead it returns a new string.

Try using:

```
var newstr = str.Replace(...)
```

Comment: god just tell me how to replace square brackets using this str.replace("[","") not working any other work around? i know it will return that ...

Comment: @PeteEngineer then please post a better question with *real* code so that people can help.

Comment: i have posted a better one now

Comment: @PeteEngineer 1) It is `Replace` not `replace` 2) You still don't show your real code `str.replace("[Issue \/]","")` doesn't have any effect and can not be compiled 3) How your input string look like? 4) What is the role of `image button` defintinition you posted? I would suugest reading [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

You need disable special characters (brackets), like that:

```
str = "Example [Issue]" 
str.replace("\[Issue\]", "")   //str == "Example "
```

Comment: Not in replace - this isn't a regular expression.

Comment: syntax error ..its not working

Comment: Re *"disable special characters"*: Don't you mean *"escape special characters"*?